# Solve the equation :

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Solve the equation:

> $$x^7-14x^5+56x^3-56x+\sqrt{512}=0$$

$$x^7-14x^5+56x^3-56x+16\sqrt{2}=0$$
 now i work with substitute $x=y+\frac{2}{y}$ I did not get the result

Comment: See [WA’s answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E7-14x%5E5%2B56x%5E3-56x%2B16root(2)%3D0).

Comment: $-2\sqrt{2}$ is a root of your polynomial.

Comment: Compare with http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54058.html $$\dfrac{a^7}{64}=\dfrac{14a^5}{112}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I did not catch .:((

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the equation with $\sqrt{2}^7$ and let $t=\sqrt{2}x$. Then we get:
$$ t^7-28t^5+224t^3-448t+256=0$$
Then try with integer candidates: $\{\pm1, \pm2,\pm 4,\pm 8,...\pm 256\}$ We get 
$$(t+4)(t^6 - 4t^5 - 12t^4 + 48t^3 + 32t^2 - 128t + 64)=0$$

At the and we get $$(t + 4) (t^3 - 2t^2 - 8t + 8)^2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

for your first equation: one solution is $$x=2\sqrt{2}$$ and you can divide by $$x-2\sqrt{2}$$
and your equation can be written as $$\left( x+2\,\sqrt {2} \right)  \left( \sqrt {2}{x}^{2}-{x}^{3}-2\,
\sqrt {2}+4\,x \right) ^{2}
$$